# Why does the s3 manager delete in batch size of 100. Can I increase this limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

As per the S3 Manager docs

[AWS SDK for Go API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/#NewBatchDeleteWithClient)

```
const (
// DefaultBatchSize is the batch size we initialize when constructing a batch delete client.
// This value is used when calling DeleteObjects. This represents how many objects to delete
// per DeleteObjects call.
DefaultBatchSize = 100
```

)

The default batch size is 100. What's the maximum size I can use for this variable ? Or is not meant to be changed ? What would be the repercussions of making it a very large number like 1000000 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the API docs for `DeleteObjects`, which is what the golang sdk uses when batching, the max number of keys you can provide per request is 1000 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObjects.html The S3 manager's `NewBatchDelete` client can take as many objects as you provide it, and will automatically batch them into the specified size to make the API calls. You can find the relevant code here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/v1.25.45/service/s3/s3manager/batch.go#L301